# How do I record button input(s) from Xamarin.iOS into txt file?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to use the storyboard button, and when it is pressed, record it in a text file.

Then, when another button is pressed, it be recorded in the same text file.

Then, record user input from a text box (know how to do this, except) into the same file we were working with before.

And at last, save it to the SpecialFolder.Documents folder. (I know how to do this)

Thanks

Comment: @Jason Explination?

Comment: just writing text to a file can be done with the standard .NET File IO classes.  It's unclear from you question what exactly you don't know how to do.  Perhaps if you posted the relevant code and clearly explained what specific problem you don't know how to solve?